# Sqlite3.interfaceError: Incorrect number of bindiga supplies: the current statement uses 3, and there is 1 supplied

Tags: sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

Please i encounter this error while running my app, how do i go about it.

CODE:

db= get_db()
db.executemany('insert into users(name,email,massage) values(?,?,?)', [name,email,massage])

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The [`executemany` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) expects a list of sequences (eg lists, tuples) as the argument. Changing the argument from `[name,email,massage]` to `[[name,email,massage]]` will cure the problem. The posted syntax will work if `executemany` is replaced by `execute` method. It is unclear from context which correction is appropriate.